# Cannot git push to SourceHut using SSH

Tags: ssh, git

I recently made an account on SourceHut to have a online repository. I followed the [directions](https://man.sr.ht/tutorials/set-up-account-and-git.md) and generated the SSH key pair and pasted the public key. When trying to git push, an Ubuntu prompt appears saying a remote site is trying to access my ssh key and asks me for my password but, after inputting it and clicking to allow access, the prompt appears again over and over no matter how many times I input the password. My only way out is to click the cancel button and then I get the message from git that agent blocked the action.

I have 22.04 and already did the following to no avail:

```
sudo apt install openssh-server

sudo ufw allow ssh

stat --format '%a' <file>
```

With the last one I confirmed files already have 600 and 644 status.
Is there any more I can do on my side or do I reach SourceHut for answers?

Comment: You shouldn't need *either* openssh-server *or* to allow SSH in ufw on your system - both these relate to *incoming* SSH connections. Are you sure it is asking for your passWORD - not for the passPHRASE that you set when generating the keys?

Comment: YES THAT WAS IT!!
...sorry for the hassle guys. I'm mexican and have Ubuntu set in spanish so both password and passphrase seem to be translated as "contraseña" so that's why I assumed the former.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So to mark this as answered, turns out it was merely asking me for the passphrase but the spanish Ubuntu setting translates both passphrase and password equally so I had mixed them.

So passphrase it is.